# Can I bypass layer 3/IP to send a TCP packet?

Tags: networking, tcp

As I know We can just use a Ethernet/layer 2 address to communicate with LAN device. But for a WAN device IP/layer 3 address is required.

so TCP is in OSI 4th layer above IP layer. my question is can I craft a TCP packet and send it via ethernet/layer 2 address over a LAN Network, which it basically bypasses the 3rd layer/IP layer?

Comment: While in theory you might be able to do this what would be the actual goal here? What purpose would it serve? In addition if you look at the classic ISO OSI model you'd need some definition of a replacement for layer three - but that's theory and not real world.

Comment: Mind you, the current infrastructure forwards packets / bits over based on the current OSI model. So if you decided to make a TCP packet that is non-standard (not routable), it may just get dropped.

Comment: First of all, welcome to Super User! We are always glad to help, but you apparently have two Super User accounts: [this one](https://superuser.com/users/867197/whoami) and [this one](https://superuser.com/users/867222/whoami). Please take the time to utilize the following Help Center tutorial and ask the Super User staff to merge your accounts: [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](https://superuser.com/help/merging-accounts)

Comment: Please add a tag for the OS you are interested in. On Linux, you can use packet sockets (layer 2) or raw sockets (raw datagram, not TCP), see `man 7 packet` and `man 7 raw`

Comment: You appear to have created two accounts. Please go to [the Contact page](/contact) and select “I need to merge user profiles”.

Answer (score 0):

On a LAN this could work, in theory, because you only have switches and hub's.
So the destination MAC-address will be the correct one. But...

You will have to write a OS for both your source and destination system that will ALWAYS skip the IP layer and read the payload of your frame as a TCP packet.

The 'ALWAYS' above is necessary because it's possible to create a TCP-packet that can be interpreted as a valid IP-packet, but this packet will never have the same meaning because TCP and IP do completely different things.

A IP packet also defines what kind of protocol the contents uses, so by skipping IP, it will also no longer be possible to use UDP, ICMP, ...

On a WAN it will certainly not work because you have to pass routers. The original packet needs to have the MAC of the first router and not the MAC of the final system.

So in practice, it would be a terrible idea: It will be a lot of work to create the OS. It will break all protocols that are not inside TCP and it will break communication with systems outside the LAN.

Answer (score 0):

> my question is can I craft a TCP packet and send it via ethernet/layer 2 address over a LAN Network

Almost all protocols in any communication medium have headers and sometimes trailers.  Many protocols also say "byte X means this" and you can't tell anything that processes that protocol (like a network card or TCP/IP stack) to do anything different.  Unless the protocol allows it, but low level protocols typically don't for performance.

Take the Ethernet frame for example:

[image]

Now compare with a TCP segment.

[image: enter code here]

So what happens if the network card gets the "Source Port" and "Destination Port" instead of the "Preamble"?  Here's what the preamble does:

> The preamble of an Ethernet packet consists of a 56-bit (seven-byte)
>   pattern of alternating 1 and 0 bits, allowing devices on the network
>   to easily synchronize their receiver clocks, which is followed by the
>   SFD to mark a new incoming frame.

So if, with the right drivers, you manage to get an Ethernet transceiver to send anything but alternating 1s and 0s for those first 7 bytes, the other ends won't be able to lock on to the data and the receiving end won't get them.  The next field, the "Start Frame Delimiter", is simply a 1 byte pattern that is different to break the pattern and tell the hardware real data is coming in.

It's possible and likely that most networking hardware these days generates the preamble and start frame delimiter automatically.

So probably the real thing you have control of on the lowest level is the destination address.  You can see now that you can't put the source port bytes here and then follow up with the destination port bytes and reach anything unless by some weird chance something on the network has a matching MAC address, and unless your MAC address matches the source, you won't get a reply back either.

So you're really asking if you can craft your own *Ethernet frame* with an *IP packet* in it with a *TCP segment* wrapped inside of that.

It's possible under Linux - simply search "Linux generate ethernet frame" and various tools will come up.  You can then make your frames and put IP, TCP, whatever protocol you want.  [Read this](https://austinmarton.wordpress.com/2011/09/14/sending-raw-ethernet-packets-from-a-specific-interface-in-c-on-linux/).